# How to export the output to excel sheet in python 3?

Tags: python

I have the following python code which gives two sets of numerical results. I want to use the output for my computation. After each code run I copy the output manually to excel sheet that takes a lot of time. I want to export the numerical values generated by the two print commands to a single excel sheet. My code is

```
c,mu,fe,lam,r=1,1,20,0.9,0.1
LT=map(lambda x:x/fe,range(0,401))
for fg in LT:
    f=fg-(1-r)*fe
    if f<=0:
        qe=0
    else:
        if lam<=mu-c*(1-r)/f:
            qe=1
        elif mu-c*(1-r)/f<lam<=mu/r-c*(1-r)/(r*f):
            qe=(mu-lam*r)/(lam*(1-r))-c/(lam*f)
        elif mu/r-c*(1-r)/(r*f)<lam:
            qe=0
    Sqe=c*(lam*qe*(1-r)+lam*r)/(mu-lam*r-qe*lam*(1-r))
    S0=c*lam*r/(mu-lam*r)
    print("%11.6f %.6f %f %f"% (fg,qe,Sqe,S0))
import numpy as np
p=np.zeros(1002)
import math
for fg in LT:
    f=fg-(1-r)*fe
    rho=lam/mu
    if f<=0:
        ne=0
    else:
        ne=math.floor(mu*f/(c*(1-r)))
    if rho!=1:
        p[0]=(1-rho)*(1-r*rho)/(1-r*rho*(1-r)*rho**(ne+1))
    else:
        p[0]=1/(ne+1)
    for n in range(1,1001):
        if n<ne:
            p[n]=p[0]*rho**n
        else:
            p[n]=p[0]*rho**n*r**(n-ne)
    Sne=sum(p[n]*lam*c*(n+1)/mu for n in range(0,ne))+sum(p[n]*lam*r*c*(n+1)/mu for n in range(ne,1001))
    Sn0=sum(p[n]*lam*r*c*(n+1)/mu for n in range(0,1001))
    print("%11.6f %.6f %f %f"%(fg,ne,Sne,Sn0))
```

Comment: Did you mean to post this in SO? Anyways, I would use the `pandas` library, and the function `pandas.from_csv`

Answer (score 1):

Numpy as a module to export in .csv that is a format readable by Excel.

I personally googled it last year and it turned out someone just answered that in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081008/dump-a-numpy-array-into-a-csv-file

Also you'll need to convert into a numpy array.

Comment: Eh, I'm not a fan of this. Anyways, you shouldn't answer clearly off-topic questions. That is reputation farming

Comment: @RushabhMehta Off-topic? He's asking a python question. It's misclassed, though, but I think I can help so I answered because I actually experienced having that question.

Comment: First, Python questions are off-topic unless the question itself is math related, solely using Python as a tool. Moreover, csv to numpy isn't even a great suggestion. There's a reason pandas exists.

Comment: @RushabhMehta Not only is Pandas waaaaay too complex for the OP's needs, but your suggestion is also the wrong way around.